# Counting: How many of the customers in a survey watched both films?

Tags: combinatorics

A customer survey was done on $290$ customers.  It showed that $228$ customers watched film A, $78$ watched film B, and $34$ customers watched neither film.  How many customers watched both film A and film B?

Attempt:
\begin{align}
 228+78 & = 306\\
 306-34 & = 272\\
 290-272 & = 18
\end{align}
Answer: $18$ customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subtract $34$ from $290$ first. This tells you how many people $(290-34=256)$ watched (at least) one movie. Now you can count
$$N(A \cup B) = N (A) + N (B) - N (A \cap B)$$
gives you
$$256=228+78-N (A \cap B)$$
so $N (A \cap B) = 50$.

Answer (score 0):

if there are 290 customers and 34 watched neither then 256 customers= only film A+ only film B+ both films
Also 228+78= only film A+ only film B+ 2*both films
hence using algebra the answer to your question becomes 228+78-256=50